# Existence of $f_n(t)=o(f(t))$ where $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics

> Let $(f_n)$ a sequence of functions over $\mathbb{R}$ to  $\mathbb{R}$,
>
> Show that there exist $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n(t)=o(f(t))$

I suspect that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$,

Anyway, Does I have to found an example or can I prove the existence without finding an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f_n$ does not have to converge pointwise to anything. It can be any sequence of functions whatsoever.

You have to prove that $f$ exists. Proofs of existence can be constructive or non-constructive (e.g., by contradiction).  That said, "constructive" does not mean having an explicit formula like "$f(x) = 23x^9$". You can't have such a formula since $f_n$ are not known. The best thing to hope for is an explicit formula *in terms of* $f_n$. This is what the suggestion below gives.

**Hint**. Define $f$ piecewise, e.g., 
$$
f(x) = m\cdot\max(f_1(x),\dots,f_m(x)) \quad \text{ when } \ m\le x<m+1
$$

Answer (score 2):

This problem, with the solution the same as in the accepted answer, is historically important as the first published use of a diagonalization, by Paul Du Bois-Reymond.

Comment: What did you mean by "as the first published use of a diagonalization" ?

Comment: I mean that DB-R published his proof about 15 years before Cantor's diagonal argument and that it is generally considered the first argument in that style.

Comment: Ok, it's interesting. Do you know where can I found his proof ?

Comment: The most commonly cited is: P. du Bois-Reymond, *Ueber asymptotische Werte...*, Mathematische Annalen 8:363-414, 1875, but it could have also been there in some of his earlier papers.